# Slow MDX Queries

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssrs-2012

I have a query which builds a month to date and year to date SSRS report for the current month & year using parameters passed to the query. The problem is that because of there are so many customers, part numbers, etc. the query is taking way too long to execute. Is there any way to write the query better or to speed it up. Sorry, I'm very new to this. Below is the query...

```
  WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now(),'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
    '[Date].[Dates].[Day].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today] + ']' 

  MEMBER [Measures].[Quantity Shipped MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Quantity Shipped]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Quantity Shipped YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Quantity Shipped]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Amount MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Amount YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Cost Amount MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Cost Amount - Sales]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Cost Amount YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Cost Amount - Sales]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Margin MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Margin]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Margin YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Sales Margin]
    )
 MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Quantity MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Quantity]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Quantity YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Quantity]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Turnover MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Turnover]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Turnover YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Turnover]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forcast Cost MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Cost]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Cost YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Total Cost]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Margin MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Margin]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Forecast Margin YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Forecast Margin]
    )
  MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Quantity MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Budget Quantity]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Quantity YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Budget Quantity]
    )  
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Turnover MTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Turnover]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Turnover YTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Turnover]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Cost MTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Cost]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Cost YTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Total Cost]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Margin MTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       MTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Margin]
     ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Budget Margin YTD] AS 
     Sum
     (
       YTD([Date].[Dates].CurrentMember)
      ,[Measures].[Budget Margin]
    )
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Quantity Shipped MTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Amount MTD],
    [Measures].[Cost Amount MTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Margin MTD],  
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Forecast Quantity MTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Turnover MTD],
    [Measures].[Forcast Cost MTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Margin MTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Budget Quantity MTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Turnover MTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Cost MTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Margin MTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Quantity Shipped YTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Amount YTD],
    [Measures].[Cost Amount YTD],
    [Measures].[Sales Margin YTD],  
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Forecast Quantity YTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Turnover YTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Cost YTD],
    [Measures].[Forecast Margin YTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %],
    [Measures].[Budget Quantity YTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Turnover YTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Cost YTD],
    [Measures].[Budget Margin YTD],
    [Measures].[Margin %]
  } ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY { (
 [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].ALLMEMBERS *
 [Customer Sales].[Summary Prod Group 1].[Summary Prod Group 1].ALLMEMBERS * 
 [Customer Sales].[Vehicle Mode].[Vehicle Mode].ALLMEMBERS * 
 [Customer Sales].[Part Number].[Part Number].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
 ON ROWS 
 FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@SummaryProdGroup, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
 FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@SalesSummaryCode, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
 FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@BusinessType, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Sales]))) 
 Where((
StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string],constrained
    )),
 IIF( STRTOSET(@BusinessType, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@BusinessType, CONSTRAINED), [Customer].[Business Type].currentmember ), 
 IIF( STRTOSET(@SalesSummaryCode, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@SalesSummaryCode, CONSTRAINED), [Customer].[Sales Summary Code].currentmember ))
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried really simplifying it and then adding a section, then re-running, add another bit, then re-run etc to try to find where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: One thing I find unusual is the use of  `.currentmember` in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to try moving the following out of your `WHERE` clause:

```
StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string],constrained
    )
```

So the `WITH` clause could then be like the following:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now(),'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
    '[Date].[Dates].[Day].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today] + ']' 
  SET [today] AS 
    StrToSet([Measures].[Today string],constrained)
  MEMBER [Measures].[Quantity Shipped MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([today].ITEM(0))
     ,[Measures].[Quantity Shipped]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Quantity Shipped YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD([today].ITEM(0))
     ,[Measures].[Quantity Shipped]
    ) 
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Hi whytheq. I tried your suggesting above and it takes the same time as with the original script except the solution you suggested is bringing through additional data which is not supposed to be there. The thing that is slowing the query down quite badly is the crossjoin on the [Part Number]. Without it, the query takes 5 seconds to run. With the Part Number, takes as much as 45 minutes. Problem is, the Part Numbers are the most important and we have tons of them in the database.